# In Godel's letter to von Neumann what is meaning of maxF?

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

This is probably basic.  I am parsing Godel's letter to von Neumann and I am stuck in the following passage where he says "maxF"

> One can obviously easily construct a Turing machine, which for every
> formula F in first order predicate logic and every natural number n,
> allows one to decide if there is a proof of F of length n (length =
> number of symbols). Let Ψ(F, n) be the number of steps the machine
> requires for this and let ϕ(n) = maxF Ψ(F, n).

I understand that Ψ(F, n) is the function of how many steps are required to decide if there is a proof of F with a length of n.  I don't understand what function ϕ(n) represents because I'm not sure what he means by maxF.

Complete letter: https://www.anilada.com/notes/godel-letter.pdf

Comment: Probably means, for each formula F, it requires some number of steps s to determine if a proof of length n exists.  Varying over F, which is the maximum s for a given n.

Comment: Given $n$, the set of $F$ that you have to consider is finite: if $F$ is longer than $n$, then it has no proof of length $n$.